# Display two digits after decimal point in SQL from average value

Tags: mysql

This is my code

```
SELECT  AVG(`page_rate` )
FROM `pages` 
   INNER JOIN `languages` ON `pages`.`lang_id`=`languages`.`id` 
WHERE `abbr` IN ("EN-UK", "EN-US", "EN-AU")
```

How can I display only 2 digits after decimal point?

I tried this:

```
SELECT AVG( cast(`page_rate` as decimal(10,2))) 
FROM `pages` 
    INNER JOIN `languages` ON `pages`.`lang_id`=`languages`.`id` 
WHERE `abbr` IN ("EN-UK", "EN-US", "EN-AU")
```

but result is 20.166667 - not only 2 digits

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the usage of those backticks

Answer (score 4):

Switch your AVG and CAST. Instead of

```
SELECT AVG( cast(`page_rate` as decimal(10,2)))
```

Use

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(`page_rate`) as decimal(10,2))
```

Then you are casting your average with 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

That's a formatting problem.  So use `FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(123.4567, 2); --> 123.46
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find helpful the question at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190668/format-number-to-2-decimal-places

Note that the linked post has an answer by ***jmarceli*** that handles rounding or not rounding, according to your need.

A snippet of code from his post:

**Without rounding:**

```
TRUNCATE(0.166, 2)
-- will be evaluated to 0.16
```

**With rounding:**

```
ROUND(0.166, 2)
-- will be evaluated to 0.17
```